# How to get the address from coordinates with Open Street Maps API?

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api, nominatim

I developed an open-source APP in Cordova (it uses Javascript) and I'm using the Google Maps API, though as the APP is becoming popular my bill is increasing (not nice for a free, ad-free APP). Thus I'd like to move to Open Street Maps.

I've been reading the [docs](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API) about the Overpass API but I see no simple clear examples of code implementation. I know the [sever](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API#Public_Overpass_API_instances) to use, that I should use HTTP GET requests and use their special XML syntax. But it's not clear how do I pass that XML to the GET request. Furthermore the examples regarding coordinates provides as input a boundary box, not a point (or a point is regarded as a square whose corners are the same?).

```xml
<union>
  <bbox-query s="51.249" w="7.148" n="51.251" e="7.152"/>
  <recurse type="up"/>
</union>
<print mode="meta"/>
```

Could you kindly provide a simple example in Javascript (for example with [`$.ajax`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)) on how to get the address of a certain location by providing the geo-coordinates to the API?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After some hours around, I share with you the working solution. Apparently, we should use the [Nominatim](https://nominatim.org/) service from Open Street Maps, and therein the reverse geocoding service. Please read the [usage policy](https://operations.osmfoundation.org/policies/nominatim/) to avoid abuses, since this is a completely free service.

```js
const coord = [38.748666, -9.103002] 
fetch(`https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?lat=${coord[0]}&lon=${coord[1]}&format=json`, {
  headers: {
    'User-Agent': 'ID of your APP/service/website/etc. v0.1'
  }
}).then(res => res.json())
  .then(res => {
    console.log(res.display_name)
    console.log(res.address)
})
```

Comment: Note that your code doesn't follow the usage policy. Now, I would say that's not strictly your responsibility as the answerer (SO answers are really a jumping-off point), but it's something to be aware of.

Comment: @Julia thanks, I amended accordingly. Do you think is OK now?

Comment: Yeah, I think it should be fine. In the end it’s the responsibility of the person who copies this code from SO anyway.

Comment: where is their documentation? cant find it on their website for some reason *facepalm*

Answer (score 5):

Another endpoint, and a short snippet:

```js
fetch("https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search.php?q=48.886,2.343&polygon_geojson=1&format=json")
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(j => {
      console.log(j[0].display_name)
})
```

Comment: nice, thanks, but note that your code doesn't follow the usage policy. You have to set headers

Comment: working first attempt thx

Comment: where is their documentation? cant find it on their website for some reason *facepalm*